# Different stages (e.g. development, production) in Google Cloud Firestore/Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

We are using Google Cloud Datastore with the Google Firestore backend.

Is it somehow possible to create different stages in Google Cloud Datastore to separate development from production data?

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/SjGHGkaIquI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developers are expected to create different projects for each isolated environment.  Cloud product don't have any internal isolation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please create different projects for each environment, and control the `google-xxx.josn` file by CI/CD
like this
[image]